# ASP.NET Core share login cookie between domains

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET Core application that is accessible through multiple domains:

```
example.com
project1.example.com
project2.example.com
```

All dns names point to the same physical ASP.NET Core host.

I would like it so that when the user logs into example.com, and then visits project1.com, they are still logged in.

I'm using OpenIdConnect with a single authority:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(
        "oidc",
        o =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.GetSection("Identity").Bind(o);
            o.ClientId = "webui";
            o.ClientSecret = "*******";
            o.CallbackPath = "/cb_openIdConnect";
            o.SaveTokens = true;
            o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            o.Scope.Add("email");
            o.Scope.Add("profile");
            o.UsePkce = true;
            o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("given_name", ClaimTypes.GivenName);
});
```

I have gotten most of the way there:
First, I visit `example.com` and login(redirect to oidc provider and login).
Next, I visit `project1.example.com` and I'm not authenticated. I must press "Login" which then automatically logs me in since I already have a session on the IDP.

How can I share login state between `example.com` and `project1.example.com`. The IDP session (`auth.example.com`) is already shared, but I don't know how to get `project1.example.com` to show as authenticated without the user pressing the login button.

It works as expected when I visit an Authorization protected page, then I'm automatically logged in. However for anonymous pages (`[AllowAnonymous]`), I would like to check if the user is already logged in on the IdP and then sign them in automatically.